# Space between labels in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm looking to add many labels dynamically, and have space between them. 
I'm able to ad the labels just fine, however, I can't get breaks between each one. Here is a list of things I've tried already:

1. Looking for an option with css with `-fx-display` set to inline or block or inline block or adding spacing with css.
2. Adding a newline character `\n` or two before or after or both before and after the string for the label.
3. Changing `\n` to include other line breaks, such as `<br>` from HTML
4. Adding a separate label just for the newline text.
5. Adding an individual layout for each label element.
6. Changing the layout from BorderPane, FlowPane, and VBox.
7. Setting setWrapText() to true or false.

And yes, the text otherwise displays correctly, I've System.out.printed everything and it all looks fine.

What actually occurs when I add newline characters is that many labels appear right next to each other, then I have that many line breaks before many labels appear again. These many labels always extend to the end of the window.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Add the `Label`s to an `HBox` or `VBox` and set the `HBox` or `VBox` spacing.

Comment: This sounds like something were you should probably use a Virtual Control.

Comment: I would recommend taking some tutorials on JavaFX layouts...

Comment: @c0der I was not unresponsive, I replied to your proposed answer within the same day you posted it. Your answer did not change anything in my code. I asked for "space between labels" which is literally in the title of the question and that was not in your example. I have still to this day found no way to get a single newline between labels, and believe me I am trying

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTest extends Application {

    private static int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{

        TilePane main = new TilePane();
        main.setPrefColumns(8); 
        main.setHgap(10);  main.setVgap(10); //veritcal and horizontal space 

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> main.getChildren().add(new Label("Lable "+ counter ++)));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(main);
        root.setBottom(add);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem for me. Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/cmP7zY7).

Comment: What is the problem ? Labels are well spaced. If that is not what you are trying to achieve then the problem statement is not clear.

Comment: I want a newline between each label.

Comment: So you just want one label on every line ? Should all labels simply be vertically organized ? If not add an illustration of the desired layout.